# Disabling SSL on home.php using htaccess is not working?

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, ssl

Below is the htaccess code I am using to disable SSL on home.php page ,but it is not working.`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^home.php(.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: `but it is not working` What does this mean? What is not working? What is it doing or not doing? However what I see is you are redirecting to https if https is not used. So.. what exactly is it that you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: why are you redirecting to `https` if `https` isn't working (line 3)?

Comment: @ShawnMehan that was a typo , I updated the code above, My server  is over SSL and for home.php I want to disable SSL.

Comment: @PanamaJack This means I am using SSL in my site and only for home.php I want to redirect users to http:// i.e. without SSL , so I tried using above code , it is not turning off SSL for home.php.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not working because your code is backwards. If you want to turn **OFF** https for `home.php` you need to check if https is **on** not off.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} ^on
RewriteRule ^home\.php$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Based on you comment, you need to exclude the home.php.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/home\.php$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.my-site.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Actually I am redirecting all of my users to https:// using htaccess so implementing this code with same code blocks is causing problem.
Below is my code by which I am redirecting all of my users to https:// , so how can I only redirect them to http:// for home.php
`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.my-site.com/$1 [R,L]`

Comment: I updated the answer to account for your other rule. You can use both of those rules now and it should work for you.